# VB.Net String comparison and Wildcard values

Tags: vb.net, wildcard, string-comparison

Is it possible to do String comparison where one of the strings I am comparing against has wild cards and is generally just for formatting purposes. For example

```
Dim correctFormat as String = "##-##-###-##"
Dim stringToCheck = someClass.SomeFunctionThatReturnsAStringToCheck
If FormatOf(CorrectFormat) = FormatOF(StringToCheck) then
 Else
End if
```

I am aware of the made up FormatOf syntax, but I'm just using it to show what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way is to use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) - that's what they are for.

This is the regular expression that matches the format you have posted:

```
^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}$
```

Comment: Thanks Oded, I'm gonna look into this now. I will mark your answer as correct when I have figured it out.

Answer (score 4):

No need for regular expressions.

You can simply use the [`Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator, which supports `?`, `*` and `#` as wildcards and also character lists (`[...]`, `[!...]`)

So you simply change your code to:

```
If stringToCheck Like correctFormat Then
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: Ah, thank you for this information too. I got the regular expression to work right before I saw it though. Thanks again anyway!

Comment: Sadly, it seems the `Like`-operator is one of the lesser known goodies of VB.Net :-)

Comment: I know aboud the like operator, but I find it somewaht lacking in many situations. So I use regexes more often, especially when the requirements change and I am not sure, that the like Operator will suffice in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous post mentioned, you should use regular expressions for that purpose - they are way better for that task.
Sadly, learning them can be confusing, especially finding bugs can be really annoying.
I really like http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and http://regexpal.com/ for building and testing regexes before.

In VB.net use something like reg.ismatch

Comment: thanks so much for the IsMatch comment, that saved a lot of time too!